# Google Maps Static Map using place_id as a parameter

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Does anybody know how to use a `place_id` as a marker location on Static Maps?

In the docs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#MarkerLocations it does not indicate whether a place_id can be used, but it seems unusual that this would be missing... Google use place_id in most of the other Maps requests.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently place ID is not supported as location in Static Maps API. There is a feature request in Google issue tracker that you can see at

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71012469

Feel free to star this feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications. Hopefully Google will implement it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#URL_Parameters) I don't see a way to use the `place_id` parameter.
You can obtain the coordinates of a place_id and then use them in the required parameter `center`.

```
var request = {
  placeId: 'ChIJOwE7_GTtwokRFq0uOwLSE9g'
};

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    //My URL
    var gStaticMapURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + place.geometry.location.lat() + "," + place.geometry.location.lng() + "&zoom=14&size=400x400&key=YOUR_API_KEY";

  }
});
```